# Retrieve object id from newly created salesforce object

Tags: swift, salesforce

I'm trying to create a parent object and it's children with the Salesforce SDK. From what I can tell there is no way to do this in one operation so I need to first create the parent object and then create each child object one by one.

My problem is that I'm unsure how to get the id of the newly created parent object which I need to create it's children. I know that the response returned in the `SFRestDelegate` method `request:didLoadResponse:` contains the id but I'm not sure how to capture that in my create function.

```
let api = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance()

var parent = [NSObject : AnyObject]()
parent["Field1__c"] = "Test"
parent["Field2__c"] = "Test"

let createRequest = api.requestForCreateWithObjectType("Parent_Object__c", fields: parent)
api.send(createRequest, delegate: self)

// Need wait for response before continuing...???
// id = ??

for var i = 0; i < 3; ++i {
    let child = ["Test_Object__c": id, "Name": "Child1\(i)"]
    let createRequest = api.requestForCreateWithObjectType("Parent_Object__c", fields: child)
    api.send(createRequest, delegate: self)
}
```

I'm thinking there must be a more efficient way to do this but I haven't found it in the docs if there is.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have set the delegate as `self` so all you now need to do is to actually provide the methods that this implies (ie the handlers for the request). Inside this object implement these four methods:

```
func request(request: SFRestRequest?, didLoadResponse jsonResponse: AnyObject) {

    var records = jsonResponse.objectForKey("records") as! NSArray
    //do stuff with your records
    //call createChildRecords method here. You can extract the id from the records object above.
}

func request(request: SFRestRequest?, didFailLoadWithError error:NSError) {
    println("In Error: \(error)")
}

func requestDidCancelLoad(request: SFRestRequest) {
    println("In requestDidCancelLoad \(request)")
}


func requestDidTimeout(request: SFRestRequest) {
    println("In requestDidTimeout \(request)")
}
```

The `for` loop that you have following the request should be in another method that you can call from the successful load method that you implemented as part of the delegate protocol.

Comment: The problem with this is that `request:didLoadResponse:` is called for each of the children too so how what logic could I use to tell them apart?

Comment: You could use a block response handler (a different design pattern similar to an inline anonymous callback function) or you could set a flag that indicates that you are now creating child records. Inside the delegate, you'd check this flag and if it was false, set it. From then on, the flag would be true and you could process different logic within your delegate.

Comment: Yeah I thought of the flag solution but I much prefer the idea of the block response handler. In fact that was the kind of thing I wanted to implement but I wasn't sure how. Would you mind updating your answer with an example?